# Organizing and assigning privileges to multiple objects in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, schema

I'm new to MySQL, moving from MS SQL Server, and I'm wondering if there's a way to logically group tables, views, sp's, etc in the same manner as you would with schemas in SQL Server....seeing as how the concept of a schema is entirely different in MySQL.  In SQL Server I was able to use both schemas and roles to easily manage permissions.  I've found that I can create roles in MySQL and suppose I could write a script that grants permissions on a gazillion objects that way.  Just wondering if there is a cleaner, easily maintained approach.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support multiple schema in Database, you must create separate database and grant permissions to roles as per your requirements.